# Is the express version of SQL Server 2008 compatible with databases from full version?

Tags: sql-server-2008, compatibility, sql-server-2008-express

There are databases that currently run in the full version of Microsoft SQL Server 2008, and I am looking to start developing with them from my personal computer, using the express version.

Would there be any issues with this?

My current thought is that they're the same server, but the express offers less features. So there may be issues if the premium features are currently being used?

Comment: Yes, the Express version is fully compatible with the "full" versions and uses the same file format (`.mdf`, `.ndf`, `.ldf` files)

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I wonder then why you would get the full version?

Comment: If you need more than 10 GB of space, and for the additional features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Express is a great database to start your development and you can do a backup and restore from SQL Express to Standard/Developer or Enterprise.  You MAY have difficulty going from a Higher Version of SQL Server to a lower one.

A great datasheet example from Microsoft is located [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx)

If you want to work on Application development and are looking for a great place to start small amounts of data, by all means go for it.  If, however, you are getting into Database Development or want to experiment with Database Administration, look at the [Developer Edition](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/SQL-Server-Developer-Edition-2012/productID.281182300). but you you can't use it for production.

Good luck with your development!